# Problem with reading destination IP from pcap file

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to read list of destination IP's from a pcap file, the problem is when I run the while loop a get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pcap/pcap.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(pcap[4]['IP'].show())
  File "/root/venv/pcap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1171, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer ['IP'] not found
```

When I checked Wireshark, I found that error appears because of requests made by vmware, since I wrote this code on a Kali virtual machine. Here is my code

```
from scapy.all import *
from nmap import *
from collections import OrderedDict

scanner = nmap.PortScanner()
pcap = rdpcap('/root/Downloads/nakerah.pcap')

ip_list = []
x = 0
while x < 4:
    host_ip = pcap[x]['IP'].dst
    ip_list.append(host_ip)
    final_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(ip_list))
    x += 1

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly what you need to know.

> IndexError: Layer ['IP'] not found

One of the packets in your packet captures that does not contain an IP layer. You need to check if the IP layer exists before accessing it. For example, an ARP packet will not have an IP layer and will break your code.

Using this [pcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=allen_test.pcap) from wireshark's sample captures, we can get the dest IPs by *checking if the IP layer exists*.

```py
# print_ips.py
from scapy.all import rdpcap

ip_list = []
pkts = rdpcap('allen_test.pcap')
# Limit analysis to 20 packets for brevity
twenty_pkts = pkts[:20]
for packet in twenty_packets:
    # This check is what you are missing
    if 'IP' in packet:
        dest_ip = packet['IP'].dst
        ip_list.append(dest_ip)

print("Out of", len(twenty_packets), "packets,", len(ip_list), "were IP packets.")
print("Dest IPs", ip_list)
```

Running this in the shell, we get

```sh
$ python print_ips.py
WARNING: DNS decompression loop detected
Out of 20 packets, 7 were IP packets.
Dest IPs ['172.19.255.255', '172.19.255.255', '172.19.255.255', '172.19.255.255', '224.0.0.9', '172.19.0.240', '172.19.0.240']
```